# Is it possible to have a Shopify website and a code website on the same domain?

Tags: dns, shopify, web-deployment

I want to build an HTML, CSS, and Js for my home page and my landing pages and a Shopify store for my product pages but I want to be on the same domain so that the flow doesn't break and my SEO and analytics be more precise.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

I would venture that you have two options (there may be more, but these popped in my head first):

1. Create a subdomain of your primary domain. This wouldn't mess with your current domain's SEO and you may actually see benefits from future SEO since the two are connected by a common domain. I know search engines treat subs as their own, but your sites will be driving traffic between each other and this would keep your customers within your overall domain.
2. Create a page/series of pages under your primary domain with pictures and Shopify buttons for each item. This is highly redundant and, frankly, a waste of time and energy, but I am putting it out there, nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Buy button SDK over your main content website to append the product from Shopify and utilize the Shopify cart functionalities.

I think this is the best option when you want to have a separate website along with Shopify, its cost is lower than the regular Shopify plan.

Here are some links:

1. [buy Button](https://www.shopify.in/buy-button)
2. [Documentation](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/online-sales-channels/buy-button)
3. [Shopify Lite](https://www.shopify.com/lite)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Storefront API with Checkout API also provide all the power of Shopify to those that do not want to host on the Shopify online store platform. Would suit your use case fine it seems.